# Wi-Fi or Bluetooth to USB converter

Tags: wireless-networking, usb

Is there a device, that works without a driver, you just connect it as usb, and receive any signal sent to it as if it were COM Port wired connection? 
For example, such a device that gets data sent to it by Wi-Fi network or Bluetooth and resends it to the USB. Of course it has to be set up once (network name, password etc) and for this purpose you need a driver, but once it is set up, you can use it at any computer without a driver.

I have a Bluetooth USB, but I think it can't work without a driver. By just connecting it to any computer you can't find it in device list on another bluetooth device (as phone, etc).

Comment: Even if you don't have to install a USB/Bluetooth/Wi-Fi/serial driver, you'd still have to run and configure some software to watch for the USB device getting connected, and open the associated serial port it creates and start using it. And if you're going to have to set that up on any computer you'd want to use it with, would it really be that much more work/hassle to install a driver?

Comment: it would make it easier to answer your question if you'd tell what you are tring to archieve.

Answer (score 0):

No, that *cannot* work. All USB devices require drivers, in all common Operating Systems. Up to 255 USB devices can share a single bus (via USB hubs). This requires cooperation, and that's one essential task for the driver.